# INSERT INTO SELECT with ORDER BY - can assumptions be made about row insertion order

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider this code :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t2 (code varchar(100) not null primary key, nam varchar(100) not null, active DATETIME)
insert into dbo.t2  (code, nam, active) values ('YAB', 'Yabbie', '20140101')
insert into dbo.t2  (code, nam, active) values ('CAR', 'Carp', '20130101')
insert into dbo.t2  (code, nam, active) values ('ANG', 'Angel Fish', '20110101')

CREATE TABLE dbo.t1 (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, code varchar(100) not null)
insert into dbo.t1 (code) select code from dbo.t2 order by active

select * from dbo.t1 order by id
```

The result I see from the select statement is :

First row : 1 , ANG

Second row : 2, CAR

Third row : 3, YAB

Is it safe to assume this will always be the case (assume for this exercise that you are the only user on the system).

I'm trying to figure out if the INSERT statement gives some sort of guarantee as to the order it inserts rows when the SELECT part has an ORDER BY clause. I know normally this shouldn't matter, but it can make a difference when INDENTITY columns are involved.

Comment: Why does it matter what order the rows are inserted? A `SELECT` statement never has a guaranteed order without an `ORDER BY` anyway.

Comment: @MikeD. Because he can order on id and represent the insert order.

Comment: @MikeD - I appreciate that a SELECT without an ORDER BY never has a guaranteed order. I'm talking about something slightly different here.

Comment: You may find the explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655565/select-into-retains-order-by-in-sql-server-2008-but-not-2012) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the manual insert statements will be process in order and a later insert will have a larger identity value.

If the insert was a select from another table then you would need to order the select.
The insert would honor the order of the select.
In this case your select could have variations if there was a tie on active.

Comment: thanks. Yes, in my case it's ok if there is some non-deterministic ordering for tied "active" values.