# SELECT * INTO Based on a certain order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to `SELECT * INTO` a new table in a particular order?

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP FROM (

SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

UNION

SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

//PLACE 1: ORDER BY DATE STATEMENT

) As Temp //PLACE 2: ORDER BY DATE STATEMENT
```

Basically I hope to have all the stock in stock out entry in ascending date order when entering the database, cause I want to do a running total based on the dates to be plotted in a graph. But it seems like both places are not correct.

My script is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD SIndex INT identity(1,1)
ALTER TABLE TEMP ADD RunningTotal INT

SELECT ... , (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TEMP b WHERE b.SIndex >= a.SIndex AND b.Name = a.Name)
FROM TEMP a
```

You can see that the order of dates are important, or else the running total will be wrong. So I would like to know if there is anyway to make sure that the `SELECT * INTO` statement can have a certain order?

Thank you very much!

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. ORDER BY makes no difference when inserting data! (At least as long as no autogenerated id is involved...)

Comment: You need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` to ensure that the identity values correspond to your `ORDER BY` during the insert. But that still doesn't guarantee any particular ordering of the rows within the table. Only ORDER BY applied during *retrieval* is respected. (`SELECT ... INTO` can generate the identity values *before* it applies the sorting operation)

Comment: See [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

If the order of your identity column is relevant, create your own using `ROW_NUMBER()` e.g.

```
SELECT  SIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date), *
INTO    Temp
FROM    (   
            SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
            FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
            WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

            UNION

            SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
            FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
            WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID
        ) AS temp;
```

Or create your temp table first, then use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT` to maintain your order.

There is an `IDENTITY()` function that allows you to generate an identity column on insert, e.generate

```
SELECT  SIndex = IDENTITY(), *
INTO    Temp
FROM ....
```

However. this does **NOT** guarantee the order of the identity will match the order of insert.

Identity columns should not really hold any meaning other than to uniquely identify a row, if they have any meaning then they are not being used correctly. As soon as you insert a new row, your Identity column will no longer be an indication of the date order. I would be inclined to not bother with a temporary table at all:

```
WITH Temp AS
(   SELECT  SIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date), *
    FROM    (   
                SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
                FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
                WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

                UNION

                SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
                FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
                WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID
            ) AS temp
)
SELECT  RunningTotal = (    SELECT SUM(amount) 
                            FROM    TEMP AS b 
                            WHERE   b.SIndex >= a.SIndex 
                            AND     b.Name = a.Name)
FROM    TEMP AS a;
```

Or, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, simply:

```
WITH Temp AS
(   SELECT  SIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date), *
    FROM    (   
                SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
                FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
                WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

                UNION

                SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
                FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
                WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID
            ) AS temp
)
SELECT  RunningTotal = SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY SIndex)
FROM    Temp;
```

It is also worth noting that if you have two rows with the same date and the same name, there is no guarantee that if they will end up in the same order if you run the query twice, you may wish to consider adding further ordering criteria. I assume there will be duplicates otherwise the query could simply be:

```
WITH Temp AS
(   
    SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
    FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
    WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

    UNION

    SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
    FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
    WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID
)
SELECT  RunningTotal = (    SELECT SUM(amount) 
                            FROM    TEMP AS b 
                            WHERE   b.Date >= a.Date 
                            AND     b.Name = a.Name)
FROM    TEMP AS a;
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this works

Create table and insert

```
Create table TEMPv1 
(
SIndex INT identity(1,1),
Name varchar(max),
AmountOut int,
[Date] datetime,
)

insert into TEMPv1 ( Name,AmountOut,[Date])

SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountOut as amount, c.Date
FROM Item a, Stock b, StockOut c
WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID

UNION

SELECT a.Name, b.Balance, -c.AmountIn as amount, c.Date
FROM Item a, Stock b, StockIn c
WHERE a.ID = b.ItemID AND b.ID = c.StockID
ORDER BY c.Date

ALTER TABLE TEMPv1 ADD RunningTotal INT

SELECT ... , (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TEMP b WHERE b.SIndex >= a.SIndex AND     b.Name = a.Name)
FROM TEMPv1 MP a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Order by
```

Will not work in `Select into`

[Please Check the Posted enquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655565/select-into-retains-order-by-in-sql-server-2008-but-not-2012)